# Perform a SSH connection with Windows API in C/C++?

Tags: linux, windows, winapi, ssh, telnet

I currently have two applications, one is on Windows and one is on Linux.
They need to work together (There's socket interaction between them and so on).

I need to somehow make only one application, but I still need things to operate on the linux side.

What I'm looking for is some API available in **Windows** to open a SSH connection (I think that a telnet connection will also do, not sure though), and dispatch a few commands through it to my Linux PC (To start sending some stuff).

I'm bound to using Windows API on VS2005 in C/C++.
I used **plink** for a bit, and it's very nice and useful, but I can't have a third-party installation to make it work.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: what about putty ? mingw adds graphics (but is harder to set up)

Comment: @xhudik, plink (as mentioned in the question) is a part of the PuTTY suite.

Comment: I've had success with "librarizing" putty to work with my Win32 C/C++ application.  Its not plug and play - I had to write some glue code but was able to import in just the ssh/rlogin/telnet/socket portions of putty to use as a static library.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can't really use third-party apps/libraries in my solution (Sadly). Putty may be OK, since it's almost mandatory on each PC. How is it possible to dispatch commands to putty (Similar to plink). The reason I'm insisting on this is because when Putty is something that can be found on any PC here, I can't force people to get plink (Even though it's downloadable from the PUTTY site).

Comment: PuTTY is a GUI app for user interaction, PLink is for programmatic control. Trying to force them the other way aroundis not going to be easy. Also, if PuTTY is standard, how is it installed? If via the setup package then it includes PLink. If by just distributing the executable, you have the hassle of trying to fine it.

Comment: Sadly, I think the executable is just copied. But I will try to investigate whether it's possible to force the package, or make sure if Plink can be installed.

Comment: Or just include PLink in your own setup.

Answer (score 4):

I have not used this myself but [libssh](http://api.libssh.org/stable/) looks like it would fit the bill for you.

Comment: Unless I'm getting this wrong, libbsh is a third party library. Right?
I can't use these :(

Comment: There is no 'out-of-the-box' API to do this.  That's why people have built these SSH libraries and applications.  `libssh` has about the smallest footprint delta you can get that will do what you want. The alternative is to rewrite the required function yourself, or hack some existing public-domain code to get the bits you need into your codebase.  At that point you have to ask yourself, whose dumb idea was it to disallow 3rd-party libs?

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look to ChilkatSoftware at http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ssh-features.asp, they offer a SSH API for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native SSH client (or library) in Windows. If you're not looking to do it from scratch then I'd look again at PuTTY and it's associated programs. these can be distributed with your application so won't require an extra installation. It's also open source so (dependant on licencing) you may be able to reuse/port some of the code)